# How to concatenate strings wrapped around the ' character

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to concatenate 2 strings/fields from a table into one additional attribute and have it wrapped around the “ ' ” character using an sql select statement in oracle.

This statement

```
select SISTEMA, SUBSISTEMA, SISTEMA||'-'||SUBSISTEMA AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

produces

```
SISTEMA SUBSISTEMA Concatenate
"AdZC","Meruge","AdZC-Meruge"
```

1

```
select SISTEMA, SUBSISTEMA, SISTEMA||'-'||SUBSISTEMA AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

valid code but not what I want

2

```
select SISTEMA, SUBSISTEMA, '||SISTEMA||'-'||SUBSISTEMA||' AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

> Error report - ORA-01722: número inválido

3
Error

```
select SISTEMA, SUBSISTEMA, ||'||SISTEMA||'-'||SUBSISTEMA||'|| AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: falta expressão
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

I want the code to produce:

```
SISTEMA SUBSISTEMA Concatenate
"AdZC","Meruge",'AdZC-Meruge'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate `''''` at the start and at the end of the concatenated columns:

```
select 
  SISTEMA, 
  SUBSISTEMA, 
  '''' || SISTEMA || '-' || SUBSISTEMA  || '''' AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f78abe3e2556e908ccf24ed91fa70ba8).
Result:

```
> SISTEMA | SUBSISTEMA | CONCATENATE  
> :------ | :--------- | :------------
> AdZC    | Meruge     | 'AdZC-Meruge'
```

If there are really double quotes in the columns and you want them removed:

```
select 
  SISTEMA, 
  SUBSISTEMA, 
  '''' || replace(SISTEMA, '"', '') || '-' || replace(SUBSISTEMA, '"', '')  || '''' AS Concatenate 
from VETROCOCONDUTA
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18dfdb446ca796a883e937cb4e86b32c).
Result:

```
> SISTEMA | SUBSISTEMA | CONCATENATE  
> :------ | :--------- | :------------
> "AdZC"  | "Meruge"   | 'AdZC-Meruge'
```

Comment: @Pedro if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), if you want csv format then you could use SQL Developer:

```
SELECT /*csv*/ SISTEMA, SUBSISTEMA, SISTEMA||'-'||SUBSISTEMA AS Concatenate
FROM VETROCOCONDUTA
```

Related: [Formatting Query Results to CSV in Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/)